# Как получить текст из radiobutton php?

Tags: php, html

Привет! У меня есть вот такая форма.

```
<label><input type="radio" name="question<?php echo $idquestions[$i];?>" value="1" /> <?php echo $resultanswer1[$j]; ?></label>
```

Мне нужно, кроме нэйма буттона (это не нужно объяснять) получить и то, что хранится в `<?php echo $resultanswer1[$j]; ?>` Там просто текст. Kak?

Искал как, не нашёл((

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Поместите значение `$resultanswer1[$j]` в атрибут value, или поместите (например, через разделитель) в атрибут value оба значения - `1` и `$resultanswer1[$j]`, а на сервере разделите их.

Comment: Как очевидно. -__-